# fire one set of functions first, then callback to a final function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an jquery ajax success function which uses a template to put json information in a div, then a modal plugin to fade in a modal. The problem is, the modal is firing before all the content is completely written to the div. Is there a way that I can make this collection of template actions complete before I call the modal fires?

```
        success: function (data) {

        //run generic order header through template
        $('#order_detail_header').vkTemplate('scripts/templates/header_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', data);

        //run header 2 information through template
        $('#order_detail_header_2').vkTemplate('http://scripts/templates/detail_header_2_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', data);

        //run shipment information through template
        $('#order_detail_shipment_information').vkTemplate('scripts/templates/detail_shipment_information_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', data, function(){ $(".tracking_box").hide();});

        //run line item information through template
        $('#order_detail_line_item_information').vkTemplate('http://www.isco.net/dev/webtrack/scripts/templates/order_detail_line_item_information_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', data, function(){ $(".tracking_box").hide();});

        //run pricing information through template 
        $('#order_detail_pricing_information').vkTemplate('http://www.isco.net/dev/webtrack/scripts/templates/order_detail_pricing_information_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', data['order']);

        $('#order_detail_modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
            animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 600,                       // how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,              // if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close_modal'    // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
        });

        }
```

I tried wrapping the whole thing in an function and putting the `.reveal` function in a callback, but i must have the wrong syntax or idea. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that vkTemplate dose a ajax call. If so then you have 2 options:

- use sync ajax
- add a callback param to vkTemplate so you can order the requests

  ```
      div1.vkTemplate(url1,data1,function(){
        // the cbk function, when vkTemplate is done getting data from url and added the html
        div2.vkTemplate(url2,data2,function(){
          // all data loaded? yes? then call your function
          modal.reveal()
        })
      })
  ```

Comment: hi, this is working very well, thanks! when I tried to do one small mod at the end though, it failed. `div1.vkTemplate(url1,data1,function(){ div2.vkTemplate(url2,data2,function(){
        $('.theClass').hide(), function() {
        modal.reveal()
      }); }); });` also, I added the semicolons after the `})` ... was that correct? thanks again!

Comment: yes, that's what I ended up doing. Just wasn't sure if it were possible for the modal.reveal() to fire before the other thing was hidden. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplistic answer as I'm not familiar with the plugins you are using, but it will work....

```
    success: function (data) {

        var counter = 5;

        //run generic order header through template
        $('#order_detail_header').vkTemplate('scripts/templates/header_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', data, function() { doReveal(); });

        //run header 2 information through template
        $('#order_detail_header_2').vkTemplate('http://scripts/templates/detail_header_2_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', data, function() { doReveal(); });

        //run shipment information through template
        $('#order_detail_shipment_information').vkTemplate('scripts/templates/detail_shipment_information_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', data, function(){ $(".tracking_box").hide(); doReveal(); });

        //run line item information through template
        $('#order_detail_line_item_information').vkTemplate('http://www.isco.net/dev/webtrack/scripts/templates/order_detail_line_item_information_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', data, function(){ $(".tracking_box").hide(); doReveal(); });

        //run pricing information through template 
        $('#order_detail_pricing_information').vkTemplate('http://www.isco.net/dev/webtrack/scripts/templates/order_detail_pricing_information_template.tmpl?<?=time()?>', data['order'], function() { doReveal(); });

        function doReveal() {
            counter--;
            if (counter > 0) return;
            $('#order_detail_modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
                animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                animationspeed: 600,                       // how fast animtions are
                closeonbackgroundclick: true,              // if you click background will modal close?
                dismissmodalclass: 'close_modal'    // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
            });
        }
    }
```

It just applies a counter that specifies how many functions need to complete before doing the reveal, and then checks each time a call to vkTemplate is complete.